# Error communicating with the remote browser It may have died

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know this question has been asked many times and i have checked those but could not find solution .Above error is not frequent only sometimes i get it , so i am not able figure out why it is occurring .After executing below lines of code

```
 driver.get(first_url)
    #here i open forst url the perform some operation    
    main_window =driver.current_window_handle
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t")
    #above line opens a new tab 
    # Put focus on current window which will, in fact, put focus on the current visible tab
    main_window_new =driver.current_window_handle
    driver.switch_to_window(main_window_new )
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get(second_url)
    #opening new tab in the existing browser 
    time.sleep(2)
    json_str=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
    time.sleep(1)
    print json
    # Close current tab
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

    # Put focus on current window which will be the window opener
    driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
```

i get this error

> Message: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have
>   died. Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time:
>   '2016-03-15 17:00:58' System info: host: 'BLR-CSM-1', ip:
>   '172.17.1.34', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version:
>   '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver info: driver.version:
>   RemoteWebDriver Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true,
>   version=35.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   d7ac8e9e-2c20-48c6-82fd-ce8eaec93b46 Stacktrace: ('Unexpected error:',
>   )

Selenium Server log for above execuion

```
13:21:08.048 INFO - Executing: [get current window handle])
13:21:08.058 INFO - Done: [get current window handle]
13:21:08.060 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.tagName: body])
13:21:08.068 INFO - Done: [find element: By.tagName: body]
13:21:08.071 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 603 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDO
WS (d52fe7cd-ee42-41f7-b065-ec1e853e1011)] -> tag name: body], [?, t]])
13:21:08.097 INFO - Done: [send keys: 603 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (d
52fe7cd-ee42-41f7-b065-ec1e853e1011)] -> tag name: body], [?, t]]
13:21:10.107 INFO - Executing: [get current window handle])
13:21:10.118 INFO - Done: [get current window handle]
13:21:10.122 INFO - Executing: [switch to window: {1d2e0152-8716-466e-bb62-d0a96
073fb3b}])
13:21:10.130 INFO - Done: [switch to window: {1d2e0152-8716-466e-bb62-d0a96073fb
3b}]
13:21:11.133 INFO - Executing: [get:https://myar.axyza.com/monitor/getStatsData?
graphTypeId=0])
13:21:12.173 INFO - Done: [get: https://myar.axyza.com/monitor/getStatsData?
graphTypeId=0])]
13:21:14.176 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.tagName: body])
13:21:14.185 INFO - Done: [find element: By.tagName: body]
13:21:14.188 INFO - Executing: [get text: 853 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOW
S (d52fe7cd-ee42-41f7-b065-ec1e853e1011)] -> tag name: body]])
13:21:14.215 INFO - Done: [get text: 853 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (d5
2fe7cd-ee42-41f7-b065-ec1e853e1011)] -> tag name: body]]
13:21:15.221 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.tagName: body])
13:21:15.233 INFO - Done: [find element: By.tagName: body]
13:21:15.237 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 853 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDO
WS (d52fe7cd-ee42-41f7-b065-ec1e853e1011)] -> tag name: body], [?, w]])
13:21:15.367 INFO - Done: [send keys: 853 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (d
52fe7cd-ee42-41f7-b065-ec1e853e1011)] -> tag name: body], [?, w]]
13:21:17.371 INFO - Executing: [switch to window: {1d2e0152-8716-466e-bb62-d0a96
073fb3b}])
13:21:18.417 INFO - Executing: [close window])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry, but where is the error? I see just INFO log

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ please find above

Comment: do you use some remote services like `soucelabs` or `browserstack`? How long does test run?

Comment: Always fails to the same line/code? If not you should try other selenium server version to see what happens, possible is not a coding issue.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ  no remote services but i do use remote webdriver . Depends on input. so it can be hour long

Comment: @lauda not always randomly with same error.Presently i am using selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0 and it is latest one

Comment: Try with different selenium server version, i see 3.0 is out, also you can try with other drivers like chromedriver.

Comment: @lauda i use python and for python as of now selenium server 2.53.6 is latest .Correct me  if i am wrong

Comment: Yes, you are right, 2.53.6 is the latest for python.

Answer (score 1):

Because the below line will close your browser if it has only one tab open.

```
# remove that line and run your code. You will not see this error again.
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

Comment: Actually i open two tabs . Above code snippet is for opening new tab in the existing browser the i perform some operation then i am switching back to previous existing tab

Comment: @AmarK I run your script. And it runs fine for me. What browser are you using ? And what version of the browser. Also whats your selenium version ?

Comment: Sorry my bad i should have mentioned that earlier in the question description .Please see above code modified accordingly

Comment: usually it works i see that error randomly not always.I am using firefox 35.0 and selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0 with python

Comment: Could multiple run for the same script at same time with different input be problem?

Comment: Yeah that may be an issue of browser and selenium compatibility. Try with firefox version 44 or 45 with selenium version 2.52

Comment: No multiple instances will not create any problems. Unless you are closing your browser correctly.

Comment: Yes i am closing at the end of automation. Let me try upgrading firefox to 44

Comment: Also downgrade you selenium version to 2.52.

Comment: yes so far it is working & thanks .Let me have some more runs and i'll let you know